# If condition should return true, but returns false

Tags: python, file-io

In this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("250x400")
patternIntrare="0000000001"
patternIntrariGol="0000000000"
patternMatrice="1100000\n0000000\n0000000\n0000000\n0000000"

def function():
    with open("config.txt", "a+") as fisierText:
            if patternIntrare==patternIntrariGol:
                tk.messagebox.showerror("Eroare", "Nu ati ales nicio intrare pe vectorul de modele!")
            else:
                if patternMatrice in fisierText.read():
                    tk.messagebox.showwarning("Atentie", "Acest model exista deja in baza de date!")
                else:
                    tk.messagebox.showinfo("Nice", "E ok")

save=tk.Button(text="SAVE", command=function)
save.place(x=10, y=365)                

root.mainloop()
```

Why does this work:

```
if patternIntrare==patternIntrariGol:
                tk.messagebox.showerror("Eroare", "Nu ati ales nicio intrare pe vectorul de modele!")
```

And this doesn't:

```
if patternMatrice in fisierText.read():
                    tk.messagebox.showwarning("Atentie", "Acest model exista deja in baza de date!")
```

File info is this:

```
1100000
0000000
0000000
0000000
0000000
0100000000

1100000
0000000
0000000
0000000
0000000
0100000000

1100000
0000000
0000000
0000000
0000000
0100000000
```

I think the problem is in file reading, because the first `if` condition which involves strings works nicely; the other one which involves some kind of file parsing fails. I've searched on Stack Overflow and people seem to read files the same way.

Comment: I don't  understand why `patternIntrare==patternIntrariGol` would be `True` when the strings are not equal. Have you tried printing the result of `fisierText.read()`?

Comment: @Fred Larson I modified it afterwards, to test the other condition but it works fine. I did not try to print it, I checked only ‘patternMatrice’ in the debugger. I will give it a shot and come back with updates. Thanks!

Comment: @stovfl yeah, but in my initial app I need to do writing too, that’s why I opened it as a+, append and read if I remember correctly. Can you do this and also open it as binary?

Comment: ***`with open("config.txt", "a+") as fisierText:`***: This will move the file pointer to the end of file. Therefore a `fisierText.read()` will read **nothing**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*`with open("config.txt", "a+") as fisierText:`*: This will move the file pointer to the end of file. Therefore a `fisierText.read()` will read **nothing** so I modified the file opening to ***`with open("config.txt", "r") as fisierText:`***.